# Rotation of object is affecting my FixedJoint2D anchoring point

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, 2d, quaternions

I have a problem with anchoring a **Fixedpoint2D** on a 2D object. The fixed point is used to make a circle "sticky" and I have no problem doing so IF the object that will stick to it is at a rotation of (0,0,0)

HOWEVER, if I rotate the object that will stick to it on the z axis, the anchoring point changes to a rotated point on the edge of the circle at the moment of contact. I want to find out what is causing this since I do not use the objects rotation in any of my calculations for the anchoring point.

Can anybody help me? I am relatively new to unity.

```
 void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D c)
 {
     if (hit != true)
     {

         Debug.Log("STICK");
         FixedJoint2D joint = gameObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint2D>();
         joint.connectedBody = c.rigidbody;
         //calculate new anchor point
         float newX =  gameObject.transform.position.x - c.gameObject.transform.position.x;
         float newY =  gameObject.transform.position.y - c.gameObject.transform.position.y;
         Vector3 v = new Vector3();
         v.x = newX;
         v.y = newY;
         v.z = 0;
         joint.connectedAnchor = v;
  }
```

}
[image: FixedJoint2D component is on the Large circle,]

FixedJoint2D component is on the Large circle,

**Transform rotation** of the small object **LEFT = (0,0,0), RIGHT = (0,0,90)**

Comment: The Strange thing about this for me is that the Connected Anchor has the same XYZ values even though the position has changed.